Can $C_C(X \times G)$ be identified as a subspace of $C_C(G, C_0(X))$?
I had previously asked

Given locally compact spaces X and Y, must the following hold $C_b(X \times Y) \subseteq C_b(X, C_b(Y))$? We may assume $C_b(Y)$ is endowed with the topology of the sup-norm.

This is false because the identification need not yield a continuous function. A counter example was provided here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4892858/1308350.
Now I have a follow up question: Let $G$ be locally compact group and $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. I came across a paper which stated that we can identify $C_C(X \times G)$ as a subspace of $C_C(G, C_0(X))$.
But given the problem I had before, why does this identification yield a continuous function. What is it about locally compact groups that makes this statement true? I don't know where to begin. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.


This doesn’t have anything to do with the group structure. The main difference is vanishing at infinity (in this case it’s even better - namely with compact support), then you can use compactness to show that $G \ni g \mapsto f_g \in C_0(X)$ is actually continuous in this situation. I don’t really have time to write a full proof right now, but this basically follows from the claim I proved in this answer of mine: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458198/approximating-continuous-functions-from-k-times-l-into-0-1/458201#458201

yes. your lemma answers it. thank you!
